# Renderin-Bug in Webkit with background-color and border-radius

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, background-color, css

If I use a floating, block-element as a container for an image and the image has some border-radius, all webkit browser have a problem with rendering the background-color of the container element. In IE 11 and the latest firefox all works fine!

Here is a fiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/5wZeG/2/

the css:

```
.galerie-image {
    background: #00DDDD;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.galerie-image img {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50% 10px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the HTML:

```
<a class="galerie-image" target="_blank" title="The Quadrat" href="http://google.com">
    <img alt="Quadrat" title="The Quadrat" src="http://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=Placeholder" />
</a>
```

and an image: FF vs chrome:
[image: FF vs chrome with and without the background]

is this a bug or is there a simple solution? (Thank you in advance!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a rendering bug it happens onto opera too, a temporary fix can be setting the width of the image to width: 99.99999%;

```
.galerie-image img {
border: 0;
border-radius: 50% 10px;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: -4px;
width: 99.99999%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! The new Opera uses webkit too. So i think it is a webkit problem. Nice solution!